# Q: How to remove DC offset

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgernU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Essentially my goal is to measure Node A and feed Node C into the arduino for further measuring.

What I attempted was use a buffer to not interrupt the amplifier circuit and add a DC blocking cap at the output of it, however this caused me to create a HPF and DC is still on the node as well. Is there a way just to stop the DC offset at Node B? Thats all I wanted to do.

Comment: In your schematic your precision diode op-amp has the wrong feedback.

Comment: Sorry you are correct, let me fix that,

Comment: HINT: If you have op-amps with a single supply, normally you cannot ground any input, as ground is not the proper reference voltage. 1/2 Vcc is your ref voltage.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I am fully aware of it reason why Iam having need to remove the (1/2 Vcc) off set voltage.

Answer (score 1):

When node B goes negative, the output of the op-amp will charge the capacitor via the diode. Feedback should keep the inverting input around 0 V. Not sure about stability of feedback loop. When node B goes positive, the output of the op-amp will be driven to ground but there is no feedback due to the diode. You could add a diode between the output of the op-amp and the inverting input for this half cycle but op-amp output will have to go slightly negative to maintain feedback. Perhaps you need a small negative supply or an offset input.

Comment: Why is there still a DC offset after the Cap? Should it block the DC coming through?

Comment: Because there is no way for the OPA350 to maintain its inverting input as a virtual earth by means of feedback. Node C can pull it more positive via R6 but there is nothing to pull it negative.

Comment: Thats fine, I dont want it to go negative. The whole point of the precision rectifier is to measure the positive Voltage peaks.

Comment: Then you will tend to have a positive offset at the rectifier input. How about a non-inverting rectifier topology?

Comment: Wait, wouldn't that be positive feedback and may lead to oscillations? Anyways I still dont understand why there's DC offset after the cap still? How is DC after the cap? I thought a cap can block all DC.

Comment: The capacitor will prevent DC passing from any circuitry to the left but will not prevent the rectifier circuit from introducing a DC offset.

Comment: Then why is the DC present at Node B is (VDD/2) ?

Comment: Perhaps because node C is around this voltage? Unless the inverting input is taken outside the supply rails (don't go there), the only node determining the DC voltage at node B is node C.

Comment: I honestly dont know. I had this configuration where the precision rectifier was isolated and there was no DC offset.